# Service stops Automatically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, services

I have installed artifactory and its running fine on and aws instance, but when I disconnect the service stops automatically,

I'm starting the service as `service artifactory start`

What I need is that the service needs to be up all the time when "instance is running".

Answer (score 2):

As you're using systemd,

I would prefer :

```
sudo systemctl enable artifactory.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo chkconfig artifactory on`, this should enable it to start at boot.